# Calculating the sum of the 4th power of each digit, why do I get a wrong result?

Tags: python, math

I am trying to complete [Project Euler question #30](https://projecteuler.net/problem=30), I decided to verify my code against a known answer. Basically the question is this:

> Find the sum of all the numbers that can be written as the sum of fifth powers of their digits.

Here is the known answer I am trying to prove with python:

> 1634 = 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4
>   8208 = 8^4 + 2^4 + 0^4 + 8^4
>   9474 = 9^4 + 4^4 + 7^4 + 4^4
>
> As 1 = 1^4 is not a sum it is not included.
>
> The sum of these numbers is 1634 + 8208 + 9474 = 19316.

When I run my code I get all three of the values which add up to 19316, great! *However* among these values there is an incorrect one: 6688

Here is my code:

```
i=1
answer = []

while True:
    list = []
    i=i+1
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(i)]

    for x in digits:
        a = x**4
        list.append(a)

        if sum(list) == i:
            print(sum(list))
            answer.append(sum(list))
```

The sum of `list` returns the three correct values, and the value `6688`. Can anybody spot something I have missed?

Comment: Side note: don't use the name `list`; it masks the built-in type.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry I don't quite understand, can you explain what that means

Comment: There is a type that is built into Python, which is called `list`. You even use that data type in your code. However, if you use the name `list` for a variable, you cannot use the name for its usual purpose. There can be confusion in the compiler about what you mean, and there will definitely be confusion in anyone who reads your code. So do not use that name: there is no upside. Instead, use a name such as `mylist` or `alist` or `list1` or `list_of_digits` or just `digits`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton ah that makes sense, thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking the sum *too early*. You check for a matching sum for each individual digit in the number, and `6 ^ 4 + 6 ^ 4 + 8 ^ 4` is `6688`. That's **three** of the digits, not all four.

Move your `sum()` test **out** of your `for` loop:

```
for x in digits:
    a = x**4
    list.append(a)

if sum(list) == i:
    print(sum(list))
    answer.append(sum(list))
```

At best you could discard a number early when the sum already exceeds the target:

```
digitsum = 0
for d in digits:
    digitsum += d ** 4
    if digitsum > i:
        break
else:
    if digitsum == i:
        answer.append(i)
```

but I'd not bother with that here, and just use a generator expression to combine determining the digits, raising them to the 4th power, and summing:

```
if sum(int(d) ** 4 for d in str(i)) == i:
    answer.append(i)
```

You haven't defined an *upper bound*, the point where numbers will always be bigger than the sum of their digits and you need to stop incrementing `i`. For the sum of nth powers, you can find such a point by taking 9 ^ n, counting its digits, then taking the *number of digits in the nth power of 9* times *the nth power of 9*. If this creates a number with more digits, continue on until the number of digits no longer changes.

In the same vein, you can start `i` at `max(10, 1 + 2 ** n)`, because the smallest sum you'll be able to make from digits will be using a single `2` digit plus the minimum number of `1` and `0` digits you can get away with, and at any power greater than 1, the power of digits other than 1 and 0  is always greater than the digit value itself, and you can't use `i = 1`:

```
def determine_bounds(n):
    """Given a power n > 1, return the lower and upper bounds in which to search"""
    nine_power, digit_count = 9 ** n, 1
    while True:
        upper = digit_count * nine_power
        new_count = len(str(upper))
        if new_count == digit_count:
            return max(10, 2 ** n), upper
        digit_count = new_count
```

If you combine the above function with `range(*<expression>)` variable-length parameter passing to `range()`, you can use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(*determine_bounds(4)):
    # ...
```

You can put determining if a number is equal to the sum of its digits raised to a given power `n` in a function:

```
def is_digit_power_sum(i, n):
    return sum(int(d) ** n for d in str(i)) == i
```

then you can put everything into a list comprehension:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> [i for i in range(*determine_bounds(n)) if is_digit_power_sum(i, n)]
[1634, 8208, 9474]
>>> n = 5
>>> [i for i in range(*determine_bounds(n)) if is_digit_power_sum(i, n)]
[4150, 4151, 54748, 92727, 93084, 194979]
```

The `is_digit_power_sum()` could benefit from a cache of powers; adding a cache makes the function more than twice as fast for 4-digit inputs:

```
def is_digit_power_sum(i, n, _cache={}):
    try:
        powers = _cache[n]
    except KeyError:
        powers = _cache[n] = {str(d): d ** n for d in range(10)}
    return sum(powers[d] for d in str(i)) == i
```

and of course, the solution to the question is the sum of the numbers:

```
n = 5
answer = sum(i for i in range(*determine_bounds(n)) if is_digit_power_sum(i, n))
print(answer)
```

which produces the required output in under half a second on my 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro, using Python 3.8.0a3.

Answer (score 1):

Here Fixed:

```
i=1
answer = []

while True:
    list = []
    i=i+1
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(i)]

    for x in digits:
        a = x**4
       list.append(a)

       if sum(list) == i and len(list) == 4:
           print(sum(list))
           answer.append(sum(list))
```

The bug I found: 
6^4+6^4+8^4 = 6688

So I just put a check for len of list.